# Panic when printing a nil error in a struct

Tags: go

The following code will panic when printing a nil value of an error type field in a struct. Why?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type ta struct {
    int
}

type tb struct {
    int
    *ta
}

type tc struct {
    int
    error
}

type td struct {
    int
    error interface{}
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v", ta{1}))
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v", tb{1, nil}))
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v", tc{1, nil}))
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%v", td{1, nil}))
}
```

```
▸ go run main.go
{1}
{1 <nil>}
%!v(PANIC=runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference)
{1 <nil>}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/SrzUsJ3pyRC

Follow up question: if I have such a value `tc{1, nil}`, how to print it without causing panic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tc`, you're embedding a value of type `error`. `Sprintf` sees that `tc` implements `error` (because of embedding), and tries to call `Error()` on it, which triggers the error because the value is `nil`.

If you want to print it without causing a panic, don't embed `error` (put it in a named field), or make sure the embedded `error` value is not `nil`.

Comment: the `fmt` package checks for `error` before `Stringer`, so implementing `Stringer` won't change the result.

Comment: Good catch, I scanned past too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but this seems to fix it ...

```
type tc struct {
    Num int
    Err error
}
```